# How do you close all connections to a local database in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to detach a local database, but getting errors because there are existing connections to it.

How do I close existing connections on my local database?

PS. Running on SQL Server 2008 Express

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take it offline first. THe dialog for that allows a force option. Then you can detach it safely.

Comment: I have noticed, you cannot even take it offline if there are people connected to database unless you disconnect them by getting your database in single user mode.

Comment: [Savin' ya a google](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/24/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-take-database-offline-take-database-online/): `ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`  and `ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET ONLINE`

Comment: The dialog for taking a database offline is non-interactive.  It simply attempts it without asking you first, and cancel doesn't work.  And it may take a long while before it fails.  Instead, if you Detach the database, there is an option to drop current sessions.

Answer (score 25):

**Disconnect All the Other Users to Your Database**

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

**Disconnect your SSMS Connections to Database**

If you are the only User connected to a database and want to disconnect all the connection made by you in SSMS you can goto any of the `Query windows` open on SSMS and Right Click and see below:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is a permanent change. If you change your mind, you need to do `ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName] SET MULTI_USER;`

Answer (score 3):

Manually (and thus, with a bit of effort, programmatically) you can use the `KILL` command to summarily close open connections to the database.

Identifying which conenctions to close, now that's the hard part. Start with system procedures `SP_WHO` and `SP_WHO2` to manually identify what connections are using which databases; use and analysis of these procedures may lead to referencing system objects sys.processes, sys.dm_exec_sessions, and a host of others, followed by an eventual understanding of SPIDs and an inevitable respectful loathing of connection pools.

All of these are covered in detail in SQL Books Online. It's the beginning of a pretty extensive maze, and how far you get into it depends on your ultimate goals and objectives.

Comment: This method can be a real pain, Just few months ago I was trying to bring a database offline but the application kept openning new connections to database. No matter how many times I killed the process application opened a new one. Finnaly I used the single user mode to stop application from openning new connections as I was the only user connected to it then.

Comment: Tell me about it. I have a routine that loops over and attempts to kill all open connections for a specified database, after which if all were closed it executes a passed-in script (generally, sp_detachdb). If after 10 passes it can't close all connections, it gave up. DBA-use only, of course!